# Transpile specific packages in node_modules to es5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I have(making) an Angular 12 (IE-compatible) project where a few of my dependencies in node_modules are non es5.

In my understanding `tsc` doesn't do anything with node_modules and just starts to evaluate from `main` option present in `angular.json`.

While looking for options on how to do that, I see a lot of suggestions using babel, I am not sure

1. If I should mix babel with tsc.
   Or I abolish `tsc` and just use babel through custom-webpack?
2. From what I understand, In all the transpilations, the transpiled code goes to an Output
   directory, but since I have a need to transpile js in node_modules, the output for those files
   should just be a replacement for their originals in node_modules? how do we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific overrides in `include` in your tsconfig.

```json
"include": [
  "src/**/*",
  "node_modules/foo/index.ts",
  "node_modules/bar/quux.baz.mjs"
]
```

But when you bundle for the client, usually you're not including dependencies as separate scripts, you're letting your bundler figure out where to put them. You didn't mention how you're bundling currently, but you still don't need Babel if you have `allowJS: true` — for example, the relevant change to a Webpack config would be

```js
{
  test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(foo|bar)\/).*/, // this line
```

However if you want automatic polyfills, `@babel/preset-env` with a Browserslist string is likely the best option.

Comment: Thank you Zac, I have tried putting the dependencies under both `files` and `include` options with allowJs being true, during compilations, I get warnings like: "(oidc-client-ts) dependecy name is part of Typescript compilation but it's unused", Add only entry points to files/include of tsConfig.

Comment: I am not using custom-webpack as of yet, just `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`